# Android Studio Tool Scaling

Tags: android, android-studio

Please refer to this
[picture of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMcur.png). I am fine with the code font. I can make the specific code in the editor whatever size I want, but I am really suffering with this laughably huge pop up boxes and toolbars (the windows taskbar on the bottom is regular size, for scale). Is there a way to turn down the scaling on this so it looks like a normal editor again?

I'm on a surface pro 4 and running windows 10. All other applications/web browsers are running fine on my computer except this one.